# input attr 'checked' by default

Tags: jquery, html

i'm working on a modal that has a checkbox to enable a payment gateway. when the checkbox is clicked the details div slides out, and it is set so that if a value is set the details div is expanded by default, however i cant get the checkbox to be checked by default when the details div is expanded. the .attr('clicked') method in jquery seems to be a bit finicky in this case.

here is my jquery:

```
$("#setting-public-print").live("click", function (e) {

if ($("#setting-public-print").attr('checked'))
{
    $('.public-print-settings-div').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.pay-to-print').fadeIn('fast');
}
else
{
    $('.public-print-settings-div').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.pay-to-print').fadeOut('fast');

}

var paymentGateway = isNumberKey();

if ($(paymentGateway).length > 0) {
    $("#setting-public-print").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
else {
    $("#setting-public-print").removeAttr('checked');
}

});
});

function isNumberKey(evt)
{
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
 if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
   && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

 return true;
}
```

and the corresponding html:

```
<p><input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='setting-public-print'> Enable Payment Gateway</p>
    <div class='public-print-settings-div' style=''>
    <div class ='pay-to-print'>
            <%if !@currency_codes.nil?%>
                <%if @currency_codes.count > 0%>
                <div class="control-group utopia-chosen-label" style="width:220px !important;">
                    <h4 style='color:black;'>Select Currency:</h4>
                  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Currency..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="4" id='selected-currency'>
                          <option value=""></option> 
                                <%@currency_codes.each do |b|%>
                                <option value="<%=b%>"><%=b%></option>
                                <%end%>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <%end%>
            <%end%>
             <p><span id='email-customize-label'>Price per page:</span>
             <input id="selected-price" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="selected-price" style='width:50px;'>
        </p>
```

can anyone shed some light on this checkbox issue?

Comment: Just a pointer, but it's *`prop('checked')`* to check the `checked` state.

Comment: thanks @DavidThomas, that was an obvious syntax error on my part, unfortunately the issue persists :/ thanks for the correction however

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you right, this is the checkbox:

```
<input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='setting-public-print'> Enable Payment Gateway
```

And you want it checked by default?

Why not just do this?

```
<input checked class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id='setting-public-print'> Enable Payment Gateway
       ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @MattBusche Boolean attributes only need a value if you are writing XHTML.

Comment: jQuery on IE7 will not function correctly without the full syntax of `checked="checked"` unless they've been able to work around that issue in the past month or so

Comment: tried that previously, cant track down why, but it's not working adding the 'checked' directly to the input string

Comment: @MattBusche, i tried both versions, with no luck. its very strange, even removing the javascript and displaying the checkbox only in html with the checked="checked" attribute, the box still will not be checked by default. I'm unable to locate any additional blockers, and i'm now attempting to display simple html, very strange

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.prop()`

```
if ($("#setting-public-print").prop('checked'))
```